# stdlib.h's random() on MS Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, gnu

I need to use the function random() that is in stdlib.h in GNU's c library, but am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows (I don't have options for either. Yes, I hate VS too, and there are better RNG's out there). Is there a way to use the GNU random() function, when MS's stdlib.h doesn't include it?

I should add that my experience with MS VS and C++ in general is rather limited, as I learnt most of my programming with Java.

Comment: Why jump through all the hoops to use a nonexistant POSIX function (that may actually rely on POSIX specific behavior that's not even available in windows, no idea) instead of using the platform specific windows solution to generate random numbers.. [CryptGenRandom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379942.aspx)

Comment: But... but... I *don't* hate VS...

Comment: As I understand it, random() uses a state table to generate numbers. There shouldn't be anything POSIX specific AFAIK. Like I say, I don't get to choose the rng to test.

Comment: Since `random()` is a POSIX extension to `<stdlib.h>`, there's no obligation for Windows to provide it.  There's little point in testing a function that the implementation (Windows) does not provide as if it was part of the implementation (a comment to a now deleted answer notes "I have an app that tests RNG's and I need to test `random()`").  As already intimated by other answers, if you want to use the function, you'll have to provide it on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the source code from [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git), then break out the stdlib/random_r.c  (`random()` calls `random_r()` so you don't need `random.c`) and the relevant header files (stdlib.h) - you'll probably have to make your own header file from parts of stdlib and perhaps others too.

Here's a "patch" that makes it compile without any standard library headers:

```
--- myrandom.c  2012-12-26 12:25:17.439514392 +0000
+++ ../glibc/stdlib/random_r.c  2012-12-26 12:29:16.581770976 +0000
@@ -51,14 +51,10 @@
  * Rewritten to be reentrant by Ulrich Drepper, 1995
  */

-#if 1
-#include "myrandom.h"
-#else
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stddef.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
-#endif


 /* An improved random number generation package.  In addition to the standard
@@ -161,7 +157,10 @@
    information a given number of times to get rid of any initial dependencies
    introduced by the L.C.R.N.G.  Note that the initialization of randtbl[]
    for default usage relies on values produced by this routine.  */
-int srandom_r (unsigned int seed, struct random_data *buf)
+int
+__srandom_r (seed, buf)
+     unsigned int seed;
+     struct random_data *buf;
 {
   int type;
   int32_t *state;
@@ -206,7 +205,7 @@
   while (--kc >= 0)
     {
       int32_t discard;
-      (void) random_r (buf, &discard);
+      (void) __random_r (buf, &discard);
     }

  done:
@@ -216,6 +215,7 @@
   return -1;
 }

+weak_alias (__srandom_r, srandom_r)


 /* Initialize the state information in the given array of N bytes for
    future random number generation.  Based on the number of bytes we
@@ -228,10 +228,12 @@
    Note: The first thing we do is save the current state, if any, just like
    setstate so that it doesn't matter when initstate is called.
    Returns 0 on success, non-zero on failure.  */
-int initstate_r (unsigned int seed, 
-        char *arg_state, 
-        size_t n, 
-        struct random_data *buf)
+int
+__initstate_r (seed, arg_state, n, buf)
+     unsigned int seed;
+     char *arg_state;
+     size_t n;
+     struct random_data *buf;
 {
   if (buf == NULL)
     goto fail;
@@ -271,7 +273,7 @@

   buf->state = state;

-  srandom_r (seed, buf);
+  __srandom_r (seed, buf);

   state[-1] = TYPE_0;
   if (type != TYPE_0)
@@ -284,6 +286,7 @@
   return -1;
 }

+weak_alias (__initstate_r, initstate_r)


 /* Restore the state from the given state array.
    Note: It is important that we also remember the locations of the pointers
@@ -293,7 +296,10 @@
    to the order in which things are done, it is OK to call setstate with the
    same state as the current state
    Returns 0 on success, non-zero on failure.  */
-int setstate_r (char *arg_state, struct random_data *buf)
+int
+__setstate_r (arg_state, buf)
+     char *arg_state;
+     struct random_data *buf;
 {
   int32_t *new_state = 1 + (int32_t *) arg_state;
   int type;
@@ -337,6 +343,7 @@
   return -1;
 }

+weak_alias (__setstate_r, setstate_r)


 /* If we are using the trivial TYPE_0 R.N.G., just do the old linear
    congruential bit.  Otherwise, we do our fancy trinomial stuff, which is the
@@ -349,7 +356,10 @@
    rear pointers can't wrap on the same call by not testing the rear
    pointer if the front one has wrapped.  Returns a 31-bit random number.  */

-int random_r (struct random_data *buf, int32_t *result)
+int
+__random_r (buf, result)
+     struct random_data *buf;
+     int32_t *result;
 {
   int32_t *state;

@@ -397,24 +407,4 @@
   return -1;
 }

-
-// Additional code to show that "it works" ... 
-static struct random_data rbuf;
-char state_array[12345];
-
-void init_myrandom(void)
-{
-    initstate_r(4711, state_array, sizeof(state_array), &rbuf);
-}
-
-int myrandom(void)
-{
-    int rc;
-    int32_t res;
-    if ((rc = random_r (&rbuf, &res)) > 0)
-    {
-   return -errno;
-    }
-    return res;
-}
-
+weak_alias (__random_r, random_r)
[MatsP@linuxhost random]$ diff -u ../glibc/stdlib/random_r.c  myrandom.c 
--- ../glibc/stdlib/random_r.c  2012-12-26 12:29:16.581770976 +0000
+++ myrandom.c  2012-12-26 12:25:17.439514392 +0000
@@ -51,10 +51,14 @@
  * Rewritten to be reentrant by Ulrich Drepper, 1995
  */

+#if 1
+#include "myrandom.h"
+#else
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stddef.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
+#endif


 /* An improved random number generation package.  In addition to the standard
@@ -157,10 +161,7 @@
    information a given number of times to get rid of any initial dependencies
    introduced by the L.C.R.N.G.  Note that the initialization of randtbl[]
    for default usage relies on values produced by this routine.  */
-int
-__srandom_r (seed, buf)
-     unsigned int seed;
-     struct random_data *buf;
+int srandom_r (unsigned int seed, struct random_data *buf)
 {
   int type;
   int32_t *state;
@@ -205,7 +206,7 @@
   while (--kc >= 0)
     {
       int32_t discard;
-      (void) __random_r (buf, &discard);
+      (void) random_r (buf, &discard);
     }

  done:
@@ -215,7 +216,6 @@
   return -1;
 }

-weak_alias (__srandom_r, srandom_r)


 /* Initialize the state information in the given array of N bytes for
    future random number generation.  Based on the number of bytes we
@@ -228,12 +228,10 @@
    Note: The first thing we do is save the current state, if any, just like
    setstate so that it doesn't matter when initstate is called.
    Returns 0 on success, non-zero on failure.  */
-int
-__initstate_r (seed, arg_state, n, buf)
-     unsigned int seed;
-     char *arg_state;
-     size_t n;
-     struct random_data *buf;
+int initstate_r (unsigned int seed, 
+        char *arg_state, 
+        size_t n, 
+        struct random_data *buf)
 {
   if (buf == NULL)
     goto fail;
@@ -273,7 +271,7 @@

   buf->state = state;

-  __srandom_r (seed, buf);
+  srandom_r (seed, buf);

   state[-1] = TYPE_0;
   if (type != TYPE_0)
@@ -286,7 +284,6 @@
   return -1;
 }

-weak_alias (__initstate_r, initstate_r)


 /* Restore the state from the given state array.
    Note: It is important that we also remember the locations of the pointers
@@ -296,10 +293,7 @@
    to the order in which things are done, it is OK to call setstate with the
    same state as the current state
    Returns 0 on success, non-zero on failure.  */
-int
-__setstate_r (arg_state, buf)
-     char *arg_state;
-     struct random_data *buf;
+int setstate_r (char *arg_state, struct random_data *buf)
 {
   int32_t *new_state = 1 + (int32_t *) arg_state;
   int type;
@@ -343,7 +337,6 @@
   return -1;
 }

-weak_alias (__setstate_r, setstate_r)


 /* If we are using the trivial TYPE_0 R.N.G., just do the old linear
    congruential bit.  Otherwise, we do our fancy trinomial stuff, which is the
@@ -356,10 +349,7 @@
    rear pointers can't wrap on the same call by not testing the rear
    pointer if the front one has wrapped.  Returns a 31-bit random number.  */

-int
-__random_r (buf, result)
-     struct random_data *buf;
-     int32_t *result;
+int random_r (struct random_data *buf, int32_t *result)
 {
   int32_t *state;

@@ -407,4 +397,24 @@
   return -1;
 }

-weak_alias (__random_r, random_r)
+
+// Additional code to show that "it works" ... 
+static struct random_data rbuf;
+char state_array[12345];
+
+void init_myrandom(void)
+{
+    initstate_r(4711, state_array, sizeof(state_array), &rbuf);
+}
+
+int myrandom(void)
+{
+    int rc;
+    int32_t res;
+    if ((rc = random_r (&rbuf, &res)) > 0)
+    {
+   return -errno;
+    }
+    return res;
+}
+
```

---

myrandom.h:

```
#ifndef MYRANDOM_H
#define MYRANDOM_H


#define NULL 0

#define EINVAL 23

typedef int int32_t;
typedef unsigned long size_t;


struct random_data
{
    int32_t *fptr;      /* Front pointer.  */
    int32_t *rptr;      /* Rear pointer.  */
    int32_t *state;     /* Array of state values.  */
    int rand_type;      /* Type of random number generator.  */
    int rand_deg;       /* Degree of random number generator.  */
    int rand_sep;       /* Distance between front and rear.  */
    int32_t *end_ptr;       /* Pointer behind state table.  */
};


#define errno my_errno
extern int my_errno;

static inline void __set_errno(int err) { my_errno = err; };

int random_r (struct random_data *buf, int32_t *result);

int myrandom(void);
void init_myrandom();

#endif
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myrandom.h"

int my_errno;

int main()
{
    int i;
    init_myrandom();
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    printf("%d\n", myrandom());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not guaranteeing that this will work on a Windows system, but I would think so. Unless there is some "gcc-isms" that I haven't spotted.

I should perhaps also point out that the state set up in standard random is done at around line 137 in [random.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;h=ff6bdd2b5d5a8f7633a914282f4c6ab1991df0cf;hb=2c8bfe7d6f22c4a599894846bf1715d93b295f53) - to get the same values as if you run random() in a gcc-compiled system, you need to replicate this. I didn't do that, but made up my own set of variables [which may be less than optimal] in "init_myrandom".

Comment: I tried doing something like that, but I couldn't get it to compile. I think there is going to be too many dependencies on other files that it's all going to be too complicated.

Comment: Let me have a look - I want the "answer bonus" for this one... ;)

Comment: So you would just have a myrandom.c file (random_r.c with above alterations), myrandom.h (as above) and include myrandom.h in my main file? Almost got it working. I had to rework one of the functions so that all the variables were at the beginning of the definition (apparently C needs this? Is that a Windows only thing?). Now I just have a LNK2019 problem - my main file won't recognise the myrandom() function. I've included the header.

Comment: Just needed to wrap the header file with #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{

Comment: Ah, yes, if you are using C++ then you may need that. And I thought I'd caught all of the "old style function decls", but apparently not. And sorry if it wasn't clear how I meant for this to be used...

Comment: I just made a small edit at the bottom of the post about initialisation.

Comment: Thanks. The code I'm simulating calls initstate with the time() and a 256 byte array, so I made my own initstate function which basically just calls initstate_r. I think I had to comment out a few bits like typedef for size_t, and the errno stuff, since that's defined elsewhere and was causing problems, but otherwise it works. Thanks for the help!